# Alfresco refuse connection with initial login and password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, alfresco, failed-to-connect

I am a novice in alfresco . After a successful installation and 3 months of stability, I can not logon anymore in my alfresco community 5.0.d.
The problem appeared after my linux (centos 7) crashed and I repaired the system file to make it work again.
Could someone help me ?
I have the following error message in alfresco.log file :

```
 2017-09-24 01:32:17,235 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco' with user 'alfresco'.
    2017-09-24 01:32:23,117 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database PostgreSQL version 9.3.6
    2017-09-24 01:32:29,565 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
    2017-09-24 01:32:29,592 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
    2017-09-24 01:32:29,606 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
    2017-09-24 01:32:40,100 INFO [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
    2017-09-24 01:32:40,102 INFO [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
    2017-09-24 01:32:42,418 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
    2017-09-24 01:32:42,451 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted] complete
    2017-09-24 01:32:42,468 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Connecting to database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco, UserName=alfresco, PostgreSQL Native Driver
    2017-09-24 01:32:42,469 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Schema managed by database dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.
    2017-09-24 01:32:59,684 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] No changes were made to the schema.
    2017-09-24 01:43:30,426 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
    org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 08240000 Bootstrap failed
    at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap.bootstrap(ImporterBootstrap.java:362)
    at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap.onBootstrap(ImporterBootstrap.java:723)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
    ### Error querying database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access status of transaction 1345866
    DÃ©tailÂ : Could not open file "pg_multixact/members/0034": No such file or directory.
    ### The error may exist in alfresco/ibatis/#resource.dialect#/node-common-SqlMap.xml
    ### The error may involve alfresco.node.select_StoreRootNodeByRef-Inline
    ### The error occurred while setting parameters
    ### SQL: select node.id as id, node.version as version, store.id as store_id, store.protocol as protocol, store.identifier as identifier, node.uuid as uuid, node.type_qname_id as type_qname_id, node.locale_id as locale_id, node.acl_id as acl_id, txn.id as txn_id, txn.change_txn_id as txn_change_id, node.audit_creator as audit_creator, node.audit_created as audit_created, node.audit_modifier as audit_modifier, node.audit_modified as audit_modified, node.audit_accessed as audit_accessed from alf_store store join alf_node node on (store.root_node_id = node.id) join alf_transaction txn on (txn.id = node.transaction_id) where store.protocol = ? and store.identifier = ?
    ### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access status of transaction 1345866
    DÃ©tailÂ : Could not open file "pg_multixact/members/0034": No such file or directory.
    ; SQL []; ERROR: could not access status of transaction 1345866
    DÃ©tailÂ : Could not open file "pg_multixact/members/0034": No such file or directory.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access status of transaction 1345866
    DÃ©tailÂ : Could not open file "pg_multixact/members/0034": No such file or directory.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:163)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.ibatis.NodeDAOImpl.selectStoreRootNode(NodeDAOImpl.java:291)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl$RootNodesCacheCallbackDAO.findByKey(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:890)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl$RootNodesCacheCallbackDAO.findByKey(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:875)
    at org.alfresco.repo.cache.lookup.EntityLookupCache.getByKey(EntityLookupCache.java:321)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl.exists(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:746)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.exists(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor155.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.lock.mem.LockableAspectInterceptor.invoke(LockableAspectInterceptor.java:226)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.exists(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor155.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

In the sorl.log there are some error like : Unable to create core: alfresco and an other like : Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/alfresco-5.0.d/alf_data/solr4/index/workspace/SpacesSto‌​re/index/segments_kx‌​f

Comment: Looks like more a postgresql problem to me. The database seems not to have well supported the shutdown. Do you have backups of the database ?

Comment: No i don't backup the database. After repair the linux OS, alfresco crashed after 3 hours.

Comment: In the sorl.log there are some error like : Unable to create core: alfresco and an other like : Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/alfresco-5.0.d/alf_data/solr4/index/workspace/SpacesStore/index/segments_kxf

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a permissions problem, assuming those files and directories are actually there. Perhaps someone started the server as root at some point, and you are now trying to run the server as the alfresco user. If so, when the server was running as root, it sets root permissions on all files it creates making them read-only to other users (such as the alfresco user).

So check the permissions on those directories and files, and, if necessary, do a chown to set the owner and group back to the alfresco user. Then start Alfresco as the alfresco user.

Also, if you care about your data you must start backing up your database and your content store, otherwise you are at grave risk of losing everything.